# When are both $x$ and $ y$ rational in $ x^2 + y^2 = k$

Tags: number-theory, congruences, square-numbers, rationality-testing

Under what conditions for k such that the circle equation $x^2 + y^2 = k$ has rational solutions for both $x$ and $y$?

For example, when $k = 4$, $\{x=2, y=0\}$ is a set of rational solutions. But when $k=3$, it seems like there is none.

Obviously when $k$ is a square number, we can always find a set of rational solutions. However, how can we derive it?

P.S. I've encountered the problem while coming across congruence and number theory.

Comment: The answer is iff every prime factor of $k$ congruent to $3 \bmod 4$ divides it an even number of times (and $k$ is nonnegative). There are various ways to prove this, e.g. working with the Gaussian integers.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can outline the proof.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence ([A001481](https://oeis.org/A001481)) of $k$ such that $x^2+y^2 = k$ or $(x/z)^2+(y/z)^2 = k$ has a solution in *integer* $x,y,z$ is the same, namely,

$$k=0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20, 25, 26, 29, 32, 34, 36, 37,\dots$$

The necessary condition is given by [*Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares). While stated for prime $k$, if used together with the Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity, then it covers composite $k$ as well.